# Java Processbuilder Stream to Python-Script

Tags: java, python, processbuilder

I have a minor Problem with a small Project I'm trying to do.
I'm trying to use a Java-Program to call a Python-Script.

Java:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python3", "tmp.py");
process = pb.start();

OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));

writer.write("example" + "\n");

String output = reader.readLine();
```

Python-Script tmp.py (example):

```
import sys

sys.stdin.readline()
print("Hello World")
```

It wont terminate, seemingly because sys.sdin.readline() isnt catching any input and if I remove this line it terminates just fine. 
(stderror was empty too)
I tried different things to fix this but nothing seems to work.

I would really appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

(Update: I tried to modify the Java-Program to access a .jar File instead of a Python-Script but the same error occurs here to. Using the Python Method subprocess.Popen() to access the Script however works just fine.)

Comment: *"I would really appreciate any advice"* - don't call a Python script from a Java program?

Comment: Why not use [Jython](http://www.jython.org/)?

Comment: PS py4j is a great way to get python and java communicating (rather than just calling scripts) https://www.py4j.org/

Comment: I was just playing around with the processbuilder, the python - Script was just a little program to experiment   with, so I can understand how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you start python unbuffered with [`-u` flag](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u):

> Force the binary layer of the stdout and stderr streams (which is
>   available as their buffer attribute) to be unbuffered. The text I/O
>   layer will still be line-buffered if writing to the console, or
>   block-buffered if redirected to a non-interactive file.

### Edit

I recommend reviewing the buffering all the same. The python unbuffered is a common one, but you possibly still have some buffering. Make sure you flush java writer, `writer.flush()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but sadly it still won't work. I tried to modify the Java-Program to access a .jar File instead of a Python-Script but the same error occurs, so it's probably an mistake in the Java-Program not in the Python-Script.