# Python Proccess IOException: Stream Closed

Tags: java, stream, processbuilder, bufferedwriter

I am trying to enter the values that my simulator.py program prompts for. If I try to close the buffered writer on the first 'if' then I get Stream Closed ERROR. If I try to flush instead, the second value doesn't get passed in.
(Also my python program prompts twice for a value and then displays a message every 5s).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String commands = "python C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\PythonProjects\\simulator.py";
    Process proc = rt.exec(commands);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()));

    String line = "";
    int c;

    while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
        line = line + (char) c;
        System.out.println(line);
        if (line.equals("Please enter your phone (or bot token): ")) {
            System.out.println("Enter Phone Number : ");
            out.write(readTerminal());
            out.newLine();
            out.flush(); // Passes the value
            //out.close(); // Passes the value
            line="";

        } else if (line.equals("Please enter the number sent to you : ")) {
            System.out.println("Enter Number : ");
            out.write(readTerminal()); // line:35
            out.newLine();
            out.flush(); // Doesnt pass the value in
            //out.close(); // java.io.IOException: Stream closed , on line 35
        }
    }
    //out.close();
}

public static String readTerminal() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    return scan.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the command, I had to start python with the unbuffered -u flag

```
String commands = "python -u C:\\Users\\Alex\\Desktop\\PythonProjects\\simulator.py";
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35213386/9093685